# One to One HasRequired configuration not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two sets of objects: `Coupon` and `DiscountScheme`.
Each have a connected object of `{Type}Action`, and identical configurations.
When making a request for `Coupon`, I do not get anything back,
but the same query for `DiscountScheme` works as expected

A condensed version of the classes (The full code and sql for the tables can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/M-Zuber/807661a410a88a326b5adfa7c6eb0430)):

```cs
public class CouponAction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Coupon Coupon { get; set; }
}

public class Coupon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual CouponAction Action { get; set; }
}

public class DiscountSchemeAction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DiscountScheme DiscountScheme { get; set; }
}

public class DiscountScheme
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DiscountSchemeAction Action { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration:

```cs
public class CouponActionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CouponAction>
{
    public CouponActionMap()
    {
        ToTable("CouponAction");
    }
}

public class CouponMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Coupon>
{
    public CouponMap()
    {
        ToTable("Coupon");
        HasRequired(c => c.Action);
    }
}

public class DiscountSchemeActionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DiscountSchemeAction>
{
    public DiscountSchemeActionMap()
    {
        ToTable("DiscountSchemeAction");
    }
}

public class DiscountSchemeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DiscountScheme>
{
    public DiscountSchemeMap()
    {
        ToTable("DiscountScheme");

        HasRequired(ds => ds.Action);
    }
}
```

The query I am trying to make:

```cs
using(var context = new Context()/* My database context, using a custom wrapper framework*/)
{
  Console.WriteLine(context.Coupons.ToList()); // nothing
  Console.WriteLine(context.DiscountSchemes.ToList()); // the contents of the table
}
```

If I query the actions table, I do get the contents, but again for `CouponAction` I do not get the connected `Coupon`, and for `DiscountScheme` it works as expected.

Comment: custom wrapper framework is preventing me from knowing what the context knows about the dbsets. Best guess is for you to debug through the code to see where the ball is being dropped. Also, are you using an existing db or migrations. If existing db, I'd be curious how EF Core is interpreting your context. Can you create a migration to see if it is creating that Coupons table?

Comment: This is regular EF, not Core

Comment: (sorry hit enter early) We are based off an existing database. My understanding is that the custom wrapper is not having an effect, since one type is working. I will add the generated sql queries to the gist

Comment: Wow, friend, THE Julie Lerman herself commented on your question! :D I know it may sound stupid, but you are 100% sure your Coupons table has records, right? I can't count the hours spent trying to get something from an empty or incomplete DB... :\

Comment: I know - very honored. I am positive there is data in the tables, since I can query for CouponActions and get back data - which would be impossible if there was no coupon record

Comment: Added the queries to the gist - and I noticed that indeed for coupons it is making the wrong connection between coupon and couponaction

Comment: Looking over the queries again, I am still puzzled. For all of them, the fk connection is comparing pk to pk, instead of fk to pk. But for DiscountScheme it works, and Coupon not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your 1-to-1 relationship. By default EF expects a 1-to-1 to be using the PKs on both tables. By putting a CouponID on your CouponAction you are not setting a 1-to-1 relationship, you are setting a 1-to-many/many-to-1. Nothing stops several CouponAction records from having the same CouponId. You could put a unique constraint on CouponID, but if that were the case then you may as well have the CouponAction's PK to be the CouponID. Hence, this is why I don't advise using "Id" as a PK name, but rather CouponId vs. DiscountId, etc.

If the relationship between coupon and action is truly 1-to-1 then get rid of the CouponId on the Action table, and ensure you're using the same ID value across both tables for the related records. You can test this by changing your mapping to configure EF to use CouponId on the CouponAction as it's PK. Once you do that, you should see your related records coming up.

Alternatively you can establish a many to 1 relationship (HasOne.WithMany()) from Action to Coupon, but no return reference without a CouponActionId on Coupon. Or you can set up a 1-to-many where Coupon contains an `ICollection<CouponAction> CouponActions` even though you intend to only have one action per coupon. But if it is 1-to-1 then I would highly recommend using the same PK value across both tables.

Comment: Thank you! The missing step for me was the fact that for DiscountScheme, the id was the same for DiscountScheme and DiscountSchemeAction, so it gave the false impression that things where working